# How do I take out and change the class of "drukBlokken[i]

Tags: javascript

H! I'm Daan and I got homework...

I basically need to loop through all .block classes and change the stage from stage1 to stage2 (second code block) all good but I just can't find out this part where I need to extract the class from drukblokken[i] to change it and check to what it has to be changed.

Maybe i can sneak another question in, It would be great if the for loop only went over each .block element once cause I'm calling the loop function multiple times

```js
function loop()
{    


    drukBlokken = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

    for(i = 0; i < drukBlokken.length; i++)
    {                
        drukBlokken[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

            moveFunction = stageVeranderen(drukBlokken[i]);

        });
        console.log("button", i, "ready");


    }                
}

function stageVeranderen(blok)
{                  
    console.log("test");
}

loop();
```

```html
<div id="divBlokken">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="block stage1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="block stage2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="block stage3"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm not really a master JavaScript and most things I haven't leared yet but i hope this isn't a lost cause hehe

Comment: Hi welcome. This is an excellent example why teachers need you to teach to write variable names, functions etc in English. Programming language is also in English. The world don't understand you if you don't speak the same language. Change your question and try again.

Comment: pass this inside stageVeranderen() instead of drukBlokken[i],

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jdLboj

Comment: Thanks Naga Sai that works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inside your click handler, you could use keyword `this` instead of `drukBlokken[i]`. Because scope of that function is already set to `drunkBlokken[i]`.

Let me answer what you asked:

- You can check elements class by using `.className`, which returns string of classes used on the selected element. In case of multiple classes this will return a single string same as in the html syntax. If you would like to iterate over all classes on a certain element you could use .`classList` which returns an array of classes used on your element. So to get class in your second function you can just use `blok.className`. Then check what is it equal to and change this element class to a new one again using `.className`. Lets say `blok.className = 'second-class'`;
- To loop over your list just once in case you have dynamic number of elements ( lets  say new elements come after a while). You could change your selector to `document.querySelectorAll(".block:not([data-parsed])")`. This translates to: *Get all elements which class block that don't have attribute data-parsed on them.* And once you parse an element in your loop you add attribute data-parsed on that element using `this.setAttribute('data-parsed', true);`. After this attribute is added to the element it won't get queried by your selector again. Here you could as well use custom class that you append to the element, but this could raise some problems with your class checking code. Well not problems but you would have to keep this in mind when checking which class element has.